Classifying a language of TM encodings
Let $$L=\{ \langle M\rangle: \text{$M$ is a 1-tape TM, and there is no 2-tape TM $M'$ such that}$$ $$\text{$q'_0\notin \{ q'_{acc}, q'_{rej}\}$,  $L(M') = L(M)$, and $M'$ has less states than $M$ }\}$$
Determine in which of the following classes $L$ resides:

$R$
$RE$
$RE \setminus R$
$coRE$
$coRE \setminus R$
$(RE \cup coRE)^c$


So I had an idea but I'm afraid it fails. I can share my thought process and maybe with some help I can figure it our or see some other way to think of this problem.
It makes sense to look at the complement of $L$ and therfore:
Assume WLOG all binary machines are encoded in binary and let us look at $\mathit{VALID}=\{\langle M \rangle|\langle M \rangle$ is a legal encoding of TM$\}$.
Chekcing if an encoding of a TM is legal is a computable problem and thus $\mathit{VALID} \in R$. In particular $\exists E$ a lexicographic enumerator for $\mathit{VALID}$.
Now consider a 2-tape TM $M'$ that operates on input $\langle M \rangle$:

if $\langle M \rangle$ is illegal $\to$ reject
simulate $E$ on tape 2. For each encoding $\langle M^{"} \rangle$ check if $M^{"}$ satisfies:

$\qquad$2.1. $M^{"}$ is a 2-tape TM with $q^{'}_0 \neq q^{'}_a \neq q^{'}_r$
$\qquad$2.2. $L(M^{"})=L(M)$
$\qquad$2.2. $|Q_{M^{"}}|\lt|Q_{M}|$

accept $\iff$ section 2 derived a match (else, deny)

In theory I could now declare $L^c \in RE$ and therfore $L \in coRE$, but actually the machine I built decides $L^c$.
My problem here is obviously section 2.2 is an undecidable problem.
I would love some insights. Thanks in advance!

The definition of $L$ does not compile. Can you fix it? Is it a language that contains encodings of 1-tape TMs $\langle M\rangle$? Did you mean $q'0 \notin { q'{rej}, q'_{acc}}$?

@BaderAbuRadi it appears on my screen perfectly I wonder what's the problem. Anyway, to describe in words $L$ is a language of TM encoding s.t doesn't exist a different machine that accepts the same language with less states and at least 3 states (meaning starting, accepting and rejecting states: $q^{'}_0,q^{'}_a,q^{'}_r$ are all unique).

(1) The language should be defined as $L = { \langle M\rangle: ... }$.
(2) $q_0 \neq q_{rej} \neq q_{acc}$ does not read as $q_0\notin { q_{rej}, q_{acc}}$.

An observation: Every 1-tape TM has an equivalent 2-tape TM with only one non-final state (see here). Therefore, for every 1-tape TM $\langle M\rangle$, it holds that $\langle M \rangle \in L$ iff at least one of these conditions hold:
1- $M$ contains only two states (its final states) or,
2- $L(M)$ is nontrivial, and $M$ has exactly three states.

@BaderAbuRadi I might be missing something, but why is nontriviality a requirement in 2.?
This does seem necessary if we compare $M$ to arbitrary 2-tape machines, but we only compare it to 3+ state machines.

So $L$ should simply contain all TMs with $\leq 3$ states, right?

@Knogger If $M$ has 4 states, then by the attached link, there is a smaller equivalent 2-tape TM. Also, if $M$ has 3 states and is trivial then there is a 2-state 2-tape TM equivalent to it. In both cases, $\langle M\rangle$ is not in $L$. Given that, it is not hard to prove what I wrote above: $\langle M \rangle \in L$ iff (1) or (2) hold. So the question seems to be around checking non-triviality of 3-state TMs, unless I missed something.

@Knogger Regarding what you wrote about comparison, I don't see the restriction to 3-states 2-tape machines. In the language's definition, $M'$ is a general 2-tape machine. Isn't it?

@BaderAbuRadi As I understood it, $M'$ is supposed to be a 2-tape TM with $q'_0 \neq q'_a, q'_r$ ($q'_0 \neq q'_a \neq q'_r$ being a typo) for $M'$s initial state $q'_0$ and final states $q'_a, q'_r$.
So $M'$ must contain at least three distinct states ${q'_0, q'_a, q'_r}$.

Yes, thats what I understood too.

But wouldn't that imply that even a trivial 3-state machine can't have a smaller $M'$, since $M'$ must have at least 3 states as well?
The trivial 2-tape machines you've mentioned wouldn't qualify for $M'$.

Though I hope I'm wrong, non-triviality for 3-state machines sounds like a fun problem ☺️

https://inria.hal.science/inria-00074105/file/RR-2577.pdf
This paper shows that the halting problem is decidable for such machines. It might help.

@Knogger I edited the definition of $L$, and the answer.

As @Knogger pointed out, the machine $M'$ in the definition of $L$ contains at least 3-states (the initial state $q'_0$, which is distinct from the accepting and rejecting states), which makes the problem easier. Indeed, every 1-tape TM $M$ has an equivalent 2-tape TM with only one non-final state (see here). Therefore, these are the possible scenarios:
1- If $M$ has at least 4 states, then there exist a 2-tape TM with 3 states equivalent to $M$. In this case, $\langle M\rangle \notin L$.
2- If $M$ has at most 3 states, then no 3-state 2-tape TM $M'$ is smaller than it. In this case, $\langle M\rangle \in L$.
So the language $L$ is decidable as you only need to count and check if the number of states in the input TM is at most 3.

Neat, this is pretty much what I meant with "So $L$ should simply contain all TMs with $\leq 3$ states, right?"

Yes! Now I got what you said! I missed that in the definition $M'$ must have at least 3 states. Otherwise, the problem is much more difficult. I thought you meant that it is sufficient to consider only 3-states TM which is also correct in the harder variation of the problem.

Thank you very much for all interest and help!
